# how to fix broken packages on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp

I have uninstalled lamp but I want to install it again. But when I run this command

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

But when I run this command through this error message 
`Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` how to fix that?

Comment: Actually, see this post - http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: doen't work after that I run **sudo apt-get install lamp-server^**
but this through error **
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2 (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) but 2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
again what should I do

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork`. It is telling you that dependency is unmet and needs installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem trying to install vlc player . A solution that worked for me was :- in terminal run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I then went to settings > software and updated and changed my download location from a local download to "main server".